# Most correct way to move an object straight to hit a specific point of a huge Gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

The code could look something like this:

```cs
void Update () {
   if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, specificPositionOfHugeGameobject) < dist)
   {
      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
      specificPositionOfHugeGameobject, Time.deltaTime * speed);
   }
}
```

Realise I do **NOT** want to move the object to `hugeGameobject.position`, but a specific point of that huge game object.

Best solution I have thought is creating an empty game object which is child of the huge game object. Then, move the object towards that empty child game object.

Comment: You basically already found one of the most ideal solutions to your problem. :)

Comment: You just make sure both elements are on the same space. To convert a certain point from world coordinates to local GameObject coordinates you can use 'gameobject.transform.TransformPoint(p)', and to convert a certain point from local to world coordinates you use 'gameObject.transform.InverseTransformPoint(p)'.

Comment: OK. I feel much more relaxed with your confirmation! :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution you propose is the common way to do it in Unity.

As an alternative to go to a point, you could either hardcode it or let the user enter a Vector3 in a public field.

```
public Vector3 targetPosition;

void Update () {
    if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, specificPositionOfHugeGameobject) < dist)
    {
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, 
        targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * speed);
    }
}
```

This of course means that the target position is fixed. Since your huge game object is moving, the target point must be moving relatively to this. You could code yourself the computation of the targetPosition at each frame using the HugeGameObject's information (position and rotation). However this is exactly what Unity does for you when you parent objects: It computes the position of children elements regarding the parent.

So making use of Unity's hierarchy features is acctually the most correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way is add a simple `Vector3 offset` depend on Huge `position`:

```
public Vector3 offset;

void Update ()
{
   if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, specificPositionOfHugeGameobject) < dist)
   {
      transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, hugePosition + offset, Time.deltaTime * speed);
   }
}
```

Now play with `offset` in inspector.